# auditd real-time events processing C/C++

Tags: c++, c, audit

I'm trying to write a process in C/C++ that will analyze auditd events in real time.

Currently, I'm using the af_unix plugin to read the audit events from Unix socket (`/var/run/audisp_events` by default).

I tried using `select()`, `recv()` to consume the events from the socket like this:

```
select(FD_SETSIZE, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
recv(sockfd, message, size, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

And then sending to auparse callback to parse the buffer similer to this [example](https://github.com/packetstash/auditd/blob/master/contrib/plugin/audisp-example.c):

```
auparse_feed(au, buf, (size_t)len);
auparse_flush_feed(au);
```

The issue here is that auditd events can be multi-records events (like SYSCALL) and use the `recv()` only consume some of the records and not all of them, so in the parsing callback, I don't have all the information.

Then I tried using `getline()` to consume one record at a time but I still cannot tell if the record is one record event or muli-records events.

After reading the auditd documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sec-Audit_Record_Types.html), I found this:

`EOE     Triggered to record the end of a multi-record event.`

I can use this to know when to stop consuming (because `getline()` is a blocking operation) but the `EOE` event only exists in multi-records events.

My questions are:

- Is using `af_unix` plugin is the best way to consume auditd events in real-time?
- Is there any way to know from the record information if this is a multi-records event? if no, is there any documentation on what events are multi-records events?

Comment: Pick a language, C and C++ are two distinct languages.

Comment: It doesn't matter for me if it is C or C++

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Audit Dispatcher (audisp) plugin for this.

Here are some resources:

- [SLES documentation](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_security/data/sec_audit_audisp.html) on audisp
- [Tutorial from auditd author](http://security-plus-data-science.blogspot.com/2017/04/writing-basic-audispd-plugin.html)
- [Sample application](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/contrib/plugin/audisp-example.c) -- fill in the `handle_event` function

For the number of records in an event, call [auparse_get_num_records](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/auparse_get_num_records.3.html).